# Logster displaying empty log messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, discourse, logster

I'm using `logster gem` to display logs. Everything is working fine except that no log messages are being displayed. 
Can anyone help me with this problem?

In the network tab in my browser console, I can see that the GET request at

`"/logs/messages.json?filter=0_1_2_3_4_5"`

is returning empty messages as

`{messages: [], total: 0, search: "", filter: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}`

My Redis server is up and running. And I've set up the Logster store in `application.rb` as

`Logster.store = Logster::RedisStore.new`

In my `routes.rb` I've set up the routes as

`mount Logster::Web => "/logs"`.

As shown [here](http://logster.info/logs/) a list of log messages should be shown but mine is just plain white background as there are no log messages.

Comment: So, after hours of going through the code and looking up in google for a possible solution, i figured out that I hadn't set environment for Logster. I  had to add "local" also to the list of environments in application.rb for Logster.